# quantmod Error when object name starts with a number

Tags: r

I have an `xts` object 2Clouds. However when I use `str(2Clouds)`, it gives an error

> Error: unexpected symbol in "str(22Clouds"

Answer (score 0):

Rename 2Clouds to Clouds2. An object should not begin with a number.

Comment: ok; but I just wonder why it allowed me to create the object with the name starting with a number.

Comment: It is strange. Usually you should get a warning, because R reads it as a numeric and then it gets confused.

Comment: one update on the above; using get() has allowed me to retain the original name 2Clouds (within a r-script file)